# gnome password prompt takes ages to appear after screen has been locked

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, login

Using ubuntu 12.04 with gnome. After the screen has been locked (manually, or after resuming from suspend), it takes more then 60 seconds for the password prompt to appear. This happens with gnome and gnome classic.

It might be related to gnome-screensaver-dialog, at least this is a process running while I can't log in.

I am a bit clueless on how to debug this, as I am not sure how to monitor this. Any solution or debugging tips would be appreciated.

Oddly enough, right now, after reboot, this problem does not arise. I still don't consider it solved, as this problem has been appearing and disappearing. I have been booting befor (number one tipp for strange problems ;)), but that did not solve the problem, so I guess booting is not the answer.

Update: After a new boot, the problem is there again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the delay may be caused by sleeping hard disks. When the machine sleeps, your hard drives may be set to turn off after a little while. It takes some time after waking it up for the disks to spin up again.

Comment: Why should they take 60s to Spin up, and Why ist it not konsistent?

Comment: Try disabling screensaver/lock screen and see if the computer takes as long to respond.

Comment: screensaver does not lock anymore, but the problem persists. Besides, this is a feature I really want, its my work notebook I use at customers ...

Comment: Can you see if the symptoms persist with a live boot disk?